# ListenAndServe and Server.Serve

Tags: http, go, listen, serve

What is the difference between

```
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
go srv.Serve(ln)
```

And

```
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
return srv.Serve(tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)})
```

?

I am creating my own ListenAndServe (first code snippet) so that I can execute code and send requests to my server right after calling my ListenAndServe. However, I cannot use tcpKeepAliveListener as it is not exported. srv.Serve(ln) also works but I don't know if I am missing something if I go with the first way.

Comment: "so that it doesn't go into an infinite loop" - what do you mean? `Serve` and `ListenAndServe` will both always go into an infinite loop accepting connections, that's how a server works.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?  Is it that you want to start a server and then continue executing or do you want to insert something between listen and serve?   `tcpKeepAliveListener` is a few lines of code. If you want that functionality, then copy it to your application.

Comment: Edited my question:
Yes I mean "so that I can execute code and send requests to my server right after calling my ListenAndServe"

Answer (score 1):

Given the goal of sending requests to the server after starting the server, the application must execute listen and serve separately.

The approach of sending requests after starting `ListenAndServe` in a goroutine does not guarantee that the server is listening when the requests are sent. It is possible for main goroutine to continue executing to send before goroutine executes at all.

The `tcpKeepAliveListener` is short. If you need that functionality, then copy [the code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8fa789b68912d045de0e40a9b53951659d976a53/src/net/http/server.go#L3255-L3271) to your application.

Here's the code to use:

```
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)

}

go func() {
    log.Fatal(srv.Serve(tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)}))

}()

// The Serve loop is not guaranteed to be running at this point, but 
// the listening socket is open and requests to the socket will queue.

... send requests here
```